# Nokogiri conditional parsing

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have some pretty unorganized XML (courtesy of a 3rd party application I'm using) that I need to parse.

If the element `result/nvt/cve` has a value (besides 'NOCVE') then I need to save certain values.

Some of the XML, with both 'NOCVE' and a CVE:

```
<X>
<result id="8791e80e-f254-479f-907e-e2667f57246b">
  <nvt oid="1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.111038">
    <cve>NOCVE</cve>
    .......
</result>

<result id="c1bf6c4e-1192-418a-bb2c-a3e3376dd42f">
  <name>Dropbear SSH CRLF Injection Vulnerability</name>
  <detection>
    <result id="1817a9ea-379f-41ad-9450-e2c1d6d73f9b">
      <details>
        <detail>
          <name>source_name</name>
          <value>Dropbear SSH Detection</value>
        </detail>
      </details>
    </result>
  </detection>
  <host>10.10.10.1</host>
  <port>2222/tcp</port>
  <nvt oid="1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.807740">
    <name>Dropbear SSH CRLF Injection Vulnerability</name>
    <cve>CVE-2016-3116</cve>
  </nvt>
</result>
</X>
```

In this case, the 2nd XML `result` element has `<cve>CVE-2016-3116</cve>` whereas the first one has `<cve>NOCVE</cve>`.

I'm trying to search my document, determine if the `<cve></cve>` has a value other than `NOCVE` and then save various element text into variables for later use:

```
doc = File.open("results.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }

root = doc.xpath("/X/get_results_response")

root.xpath("//result").each do |result|
  if result.at_xpath("//nvt/cve").text != 'NOCVE'
    result_id = result.at_xpath("@id").value
    host = result.at_xpath("host").text rescue nil
    cve = result.at_xpath("//nvt/cve").text
    puts "#{result_id} #{host} - #{cve}"
  end
end
```

However, I'm not getting any results!  I also realize this code my be totally inefficient, so if you have suggestions, please share!

Comment: I can't answer, but interesting is what does `rescue nil` after assignment mean? I didn't know you can do that. Thanks :)

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš it's just a filler right now... If there isn't any result, I'll eventually fill it in with a rescue.

Comment: You can't reduce the sample XML further? Take out everything that is unnecessary. Please read "[mcve]". We need the _minimum_ input necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Your code isn't idiomatic, but the main problem is you're using `//` when you should be using `./` to start your intermediate selectors. `//` means search from the top of the DOM to the bottom. `./` means search from this spot.

Comment: @theTinMan ah, good to know....

Comment: It's not necessary to find `root` using `/X`. Simply start your search with `//get_results_response/result` then remove `//` from the other `at_xpath` and you should get better results.